# Query that returns if all of the primary keys have been used as foreign key in another

Tags: sql

Lets say we have three tables Baseball_players, Bats, Plays_with_bat

**Baseball_players**

```
player_id | name 
----------+-------
1. 01     | Jackson
2. 02     | Smith
3. 03     | Washington
3. 04     | Stein
```

and

**Plays_with_bat**

```
player_id | Bat_id 
----------+-------
1. 01     | 01 
2. 01     | 02      
3. 02     | 01 
4. 03     | 01 
5. 04     | 01 
6. 04     | 02
```

and

**Bats**

```
Bat_id | Manufacturer 
-------+-------
1. 01  | Easton
2. 02  | Rawlings
```

What I want to know is how to return all players that used all `Bats` once. `Bat_id` is a foreign key in `Plays_with_bat` table and `player_id` is a foreign in `Plays_with_bat` table.

So the output I want is like

```
player_id  
----------
01
04
```

Only the players, who have used all of the bats already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
select bp.player_id
from Baseball_players bp
inner join Plays_with_bat p
  on bp.player_id = p.player_id
group by bp.player_id
having count(distinct p.bat_id) = (select count(distinct bat_id)
                                   from bats)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adc76/2)

Result:

```
| PLAYER_ID |
-------------
|         1 |
|         4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very simple query that compares counts:

```
select player_id from Baseball_players p
where (select count(*) from Plays_with_bat pb where pb.player_id=p.player_id)
       =
      (select count(*) from Bats)
```

What it says is that the number of records in `Plays_with_bat` for the given player must equal the total number of records in `Bats`.

[Demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5373a/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT player_id
FROM Baseball_players p 
WHERE player_id IN
(
   SELECT player_id
   FROM
   (
      SELECT player_id, COUNT(bat_id) 
      FROM Plays_with_bat
      GROUP BY player_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT bat_id) = (SELECT COUNT(bat_id) FROM bats)
   ) t
)
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9b086/3)